# What is the advantage of testing for median differences instead of stochastic equality?

Tags: ordinal-data, median

I am working on a project in which I investigate the asymptotic exactness and consistency of some  median tests (like Moods median tests, permutation and bootstrap procedures etc.).

I first did a simulation study in R in order to check if the tests of interest are actual median tests or tests of stochastic equality with null hypothesis P(X>Y)=P(Y>X): given that X and Y are two random variables, is the probability that a random observation from X is larger than a random observation from Y equal to the probability that a random observation from Y is larger than a random observation from X?

Therefore, I generated data in which X and Y had equal medians and were stochastically equal, and data in which X and Y had equal medians but were stochastically unequal. Some tests type 1 errors were not affected by the stochastic (in)equality conditions, like Moods median tests, but some were, like the Wilcoxon Mann Whitney test which turns out to be a test of stochastic equality.

A lot of literature states that if the data comes from an ordinal scale, then tests of median differences and stochastic equality are both appropriate. 
But if the median of a random variable is defined as the value where the where the CDF of this variable is exactly 0.5, then for some ordinal data there it seems that there is no unique median:

```
# Rcode
# Assume a ordinal variable with possible values of 1,2,3 and 4:
possible_values <- c(1,2,3,4)
# Assign probabilities to these values:
p_1 <- 3/8
p_2 <- 1/8
p_3 <- 1/8
p_4 <- 3/8

# Create ordinal variable:
n <- 100000
Ordinal_variable <- c(rep(1,n*p_1),rep(2,n*p_2),rep(3,n*p_3),rep(4,n*p_4) )

# Plot the ECDF:
plot(ecdf(Ordinal_variable))
abline(a=0.5, b=0, col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

So in this plot it looks like every value between 2 and 3 can be the median of the ordinal variable.

Now my first question is, what could in general be the advantage of testing for a median difference instead of stochastic equality when one wants to compare for example a treatment and control group? I searched a lot on this topic but could not find anything that really answered this question.

Also, given that is seems that an ordinal random variable does not always has an unique median, is a test of median differences really always appropriate for ordinal data?